# Laravel 8 & laravel-livewire simple CRUD with array of value instead of single value

Tags: php, laravel

when we make simple CRUD application.
In our live-wire controller in edit method

```
public function rEdit()
    {
        $this->data = auth()->user()->product()->where('id',$this->pid)->first()

    }
```

tables fields are 'id,name,price,....'

and then in live-wire blade we can get this value as

```
<x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="data.name" />
```

this is very simple example.

now this will not name value until I put name value in validation rule

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'sdata.name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

if I add name in rules it will show value in blade and if I remove it it will not show value.
I have 100s of field in table and some are required and some are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `user` property on your Livewire component, then wire the fields in your blade component to the properties of your `user`.  You can then just call `save` on the `user` object.

```
class UserComponent extends Component
{
  public $user;

  public function mount()
  {
    $this->user = auth()->user();
  }

  public function save()
  {
    $this->user()->save();
  }
}
```

```
<x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="user.name" />

<x-jet-input id="email" type="email" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="user.email" />
```

You will need to define validation rules for each of the properties on your model that you want to bind to [see the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-models):

> Note: For this to work, you have a validation entry in the `$rules`
> property for any model attributes you want to bind to. Otherwise, an
> error will be thrown.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your update. I have tried my query as bellow

and I am getting bellow error

Comment: Hello, thanks for your update. I have tried my query as bellow
$data = auth()->user()->product()->where('id',$this->editid);
and I am getting bellow error
and in blade
<x-jet-input autocomplete="off" id="email" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="data.email" />
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: If I use bellow query 
 $data = auth()->user()->product()->where('id',$this->editid)->first();
no error but bellow did't show any value
<x-jet-input autocomplete="off" id="email" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="data.email" />

Comment: I got it working, I need to define them in validation rules also

Comment: But why its not working if variable is not in  
public function rules()
    {
        return [

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code so we can see?

Comment: I have edit the question please check, thanks

Comment: @Mr.SH Unfortunately the issue you're encountering is a limitation of Livewire. Perhaps you could define validation rules on your `model` in a static array to be used elsewhere.